# Django EditStamdata() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'

Tags: django, modelform

Hej,

I got a error if I load a Form:

```html
from django import forms
from .models import CountryList, Stamdata
from django.db.models.functions import Lower
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class EditStamdata(forms.ModelForm):
    Firmanavn = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'autofocus': True}), label='Firmanavn')
    EMail = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'autofocus': True}), label='EMail')
    Bank = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows' :'4', 'class': 'form-control', 'autofocus': True}), label='Bank')
    Navn = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'autofocus': True}), label='Navn')
    Adresse = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows' :'4', 'class': 'form-control'}),label='Adresse')
    Land = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),queryset=CountryList.objects.values_list('countryname', flat=True).order_by('code'), initial='Denmark', to_field_name='countryname')
    CVRCountrycode = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control col-md-4'}),label='CVR Landkode', queryset=CountryList.objects.values_list('code', flat=True).order_by('code'), initial='DK', to_field_name='code')
    CVR = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),label='CVR Nummer')
    class Meta:
        model = Stamdata
        labels = {
            'Byen': 'By',
            'CVRCountrycode': 'Landekode',
            'CVR': 'CVR Nummer',
            }
        fields = ['Firmanavn', 'UserID', 'Adresse', 'Land', 'CVRCountrycode', 'CVR', 'EMail', 'Bank', 'Navn']
```

And the view:

```html
def EditStamdata(request):
    StamdataData = get_object_or_404(Stamdata, pk=1)
# if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditStamdata(request.POST, instance=StamdataData)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('backend/stamdata.html')
    else:
        print ('somethin goes wrong')
        form = EditStamdata(instance=StamdataData)
    return render(
        request,
        'backend/stamdata.html', 
        {'form':  form },
    )
```

And then I got this error message:

EditStamdata() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'

If I google it everbody fix it if they uses forms.ModelForm but I use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave the view the same name as the form, hence Django calls the view function. You thus should rename at least one of the two.

Normally in Python, functions are written in `snake_case`, so you can rename `EditStamdata` to `edit_stamdata`. Furthermore Django forms have often a `Form` suffix. So you can rename the form to `EditStamdataForm`:

```
# app/forms.py

from django import forms
from .models import CountryList, Stamdata
from django.db.models.functions import Lower
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class EditStamdataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Firmanavn = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'autofocus': True}), label='Firmanavn')
    EMail = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'autofocus': True}), label='EMail')
    Bank = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows' :'4', 'class': 'form-control', 'autofocus': True}), label='Bank')
    Navn = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'autofocus': True}), label='Navn')
    Adresse = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows' :'4', 'class': 'form-control'}),label='Adresse')
    Land = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),queryset=CountryList.objects.values_list('countryname', flat=True).order_by('code'), initial='Denmark', to_field_name='countryname')
    CVRCountrycode = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control col-md-4'}),label='CVR Landkode', queryset=CountryList.objects.values_list('code', flat=True).order_by('code'), initial='DK', to_field_name='code')
    CVR = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),label='CVR Nummer')
    class Meta:
        model = Stamdata
        labels = {
            'Byen': 'By',
            'CVRCountrycode': 'Landekode',
            'CVR': 'CVR Nummer',
            }
        fields = ['Firmanavn', 'UserID', 'Adresse', 'Land', 'CVRCountrycode', 'CVR', 'EMail', 'Bank', 'Navn']
```

and in the view, we change the name of the view, and use the new name for the form:

```
def edit_stamdata(request):
    StamdataData = get_object_or_404(Stamdata, pk=1)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditStamdataForm(request.POST, instance=StamdataData)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('backend/stamdata.html')
    else:
        print ('somethin goes wrong')
        form = EditStamdataForm(instance=StamdataData)
    return render(
        request,
        'backend/stamdata.html', 
        {'form':  form },
    )
```

Some extra tips:

1. local variables are normally written in snake case as well, so `stamdata_data` instead of `StamdataData`;
2. you can make use of [**`redirect(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect), and pass the name of the *view* to make the URL resolution more robust;
3. in Django, one often does *not* use a `.html` suffix for the URL paths; and
4. one often does not define a `queryset=…` with a `.values_list(..)`, this is normally used to do some filtering.

Comment: Thank you this helps. I have to filter pk=1 with userID of logged in users ID because this form should be unique of every logged in user.

Comment: @rau.Codes: the logged in user can be retrieved with `request.user`. But it is unclear to me how you link the user to the `Stamdata`?

Comment: I add UserID in Models and I create a query which filter the correct pk of the logged in user. This was just my first test and wondered why form is with instance not loading but thanks to you it does now :)